# How to get backgroundSession NSURLSessionUploadTask response

Tags: ios, ios7, nsurlsession

I have implemented a NSURLSession that runs in the background (so it can continue the task using the system deamon even when the app is suspended). The issue is that

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
       dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask 
       didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
       completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler
```

is never called. I need to know the response status so I can handle properly the upload failure. According to another post, an Apple engineer told that this delegate method is not called when the session is backgroundSession to prevent the app from waking. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue? The last URLSession delegate method called in my situation is:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session 
       dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` method of `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` should be called when your upload is done. Refer to the `task.response` object, which should be the `NSHTTPURLResponse` object.

---

I'm sure you're doing this, but the standard background upload task components are:

1. Make a background session:

   ```
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *backgroundConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.domain.app"];
   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
   ```
2. Use the `NSURLSession` method `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:` method:

   ```
   NSURLSessionTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileURL];
   [task resume];
   ```

   With a background session, you must:

   - Use `NSURLSessionUploadTask`;
   - Use file-based rendition (you cannot use `NSData` based version);
   - Use delegate-based rendition 
     cannot use data tasks; (b) `NSData` rendition of the `NSURLSessionUploadTask`; nor (c) a completion block rendition of the `NSURLSessionUploadTask`.
3. With upload tasks, make sure to not call `setHTTPBody` of a `NSMutableRequest`. With upload tasks, the body of the request cannot be in the request itself.
4. Make sure you implement the appropriate `NSURLSessionDelegate`, `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` methods.
5. Make sure to implement `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` in your app delegate (so you can capture the `completionHandler`, which you'll call in `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`).

Comment: I've done all this, but I need the status code of the server response. And I cannot find a way to get it in a background session. Any idea?

Comment: @NikosM. Do you just need the `NSURLResponse`? When `didCompleteWithError` is called, you can check (a) the `NSError` object (in case, for example, it couldn't resolve the hostname of the URL); and (b) the `task.response` object will contain the `NSHTTPURLResponse` information.

Comment: But, I must have the JSON data provided in the response from the upload that took place in the background.  Is there anyway to get this JSON data?

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons I see you posted comment under [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23738200/1271826) in which I answer this question, so I'll refer you to that.

Comment: @Rob : after trying all this, for me still delegate method is not calling when i use `NSURLSessionUploadTask` with `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`, please have look at my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717350/nsurlsessionuploadtask-is-not-calling-delegate-method-with-nsurlsessionconfigura