# Session.uploadTask - response body

Tags: ios, networking

I am uploading some files in background to server:

```
let uploadTask = session!.uploadTask(with: imageURLRequest, fromFile: fileURL)
        uploadTask.taskDescription = fileURL.lastPathComponent
        uploadTask.resume()
```

I am able to get response status and header, but how to get response body?

```
 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?){
        
        if let httpResponse = task.response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                    let statusMessage = HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode: statusCode)
                    
                    let allHeaderFields = httpResponse.allHeaderFields
                    for (key, value) in allHeaderFields {
                        Loge(" \(key): \(value)")
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34821875/3418066) may offer some clues