# NSURLSessionUploadTask is not calling delegate method with NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am trying upload image using `backgroundSessionConfiguration` and `NSURLSessionUploadTask` to keep live upload process in application background mode.

But when i use `backgroundSessionConfiguration`, `NSURLSessionUploadTask` is not calling delegate method while using `defaultSessionConfiguration` it call delegate method.

Here is the code.

```
//Create a file to upload
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *URLs = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[URLs objectAtIndex:0] absoluteString];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"testfile.jpg"];
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://file.upload/destination"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testSession.foo.com"]];
config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [self.session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
[uploadTask resume];
NSLog(@"==%ld",uploadTask.state);
```

if i change `backgroundSessionConfiguration` to `defaultSessionConfiguration`, delegate method will call.

Please help me to understand what am i missing.

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: You're looking at `uploadTask.state` immediately after starting task. In my experience, background sessions are a bit slower to start. Are you sure it's not firing off later? Did you implement `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:`? Is it called?

Comment: @Rob : Yes i have implemented URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError but its not calling up even after 3-4 mins. I printed state of upload task just to confirm its state.

Comment: I might try `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier` rather than the deprecated `backgroundSessionConfiguration`, but otherwise I don't see any problem. Make sure that's a valid object and that you're instantiating that only once in your code. Have you tried watching this in [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) to see if anything happens with your destination server.

Comment: @Rob : yep now I am  getting response. Thanks you very much. However, in background mode app stop printing logs after some time(2-3 mins) and if i take it foreground it start printing logs again.

Comment: First, I f you're seeing logs for 3 minutes, that makes me wonder if you did `beginBackgriundTask...` call somewhere. Generally you use background session or background task, but not both: you want to keep a minimal footprint after use leaves your app to go do something else.

Comment: Second, if you're not seeing the app restart, I wonder if (a) you are responding to app delegate method `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`; (b) whether that's saving the `completionHandler`; (c) whether that is restarting the background session with same identifier; (d) whether your `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` is calling the saved `completionHandler`.

Comment: Rob : Yep now getting server response, waited for 25 mins and put local notification since console log being stopped in background mode of app. thanks for your detail explanation it was very useful.